# Python cannot read global variable in function even though I used global keyword

Tags: python

I want to access the variable `number_of_messages` in class `A` but I get `"number_of_messages" is not defined` error even though I used global keyword. Here is a code sample:

```
class A:
    number_of_messages=0;
    def inc(self):
        global number_of_messages
        number_of_messages+=1
    
print(A().inc())
```

Comment: It isn't defined. Why do you *expect* a global variable with that name to exist?

Comment: note: your `inc` method returns `None`, so I would never expect your print statement to shed light on what's happening with `number_of_messages`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the class attribute instead:

```
class A:
    def ___init__(self):
        self.number_of_messages=0

    def inc(self):
        self.number_of_messages+=1
a = A()
print(a.inc())
print(a.number_of_messages)
```

but you can also:

```
number_of_messages = 0

class A():
    def inc(self):
        global number_of_messages
        number_of_messages+=1

a = A()
a.inc()
print(number_of_messages)
```

you just forgot to declare the variable in the global scope

Answer (score 1):

That's not a global.  That's a class attribute.  Write

```
    def inc(self):
        A.number_of_messages += 1
```

You don't need the global statement.